# In ggplot2, how can avoid geom_rect to extend the limits of the plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

[image]

With the attached code snippet, `geom_rect` extends the limit of the plot, i.e., the vertical band for year 2016 is plotted even if no data are contained in that interval.

I would like the rectangles be drawn only if they contain the data points.

I read the help for `annotate` and it explicitly says that `annotate` has exactly the behavior I see with `geom_rect` and that I would like to avoid.

> **Details**
>
> Note that all position aesthetics are scaled (i.e. they will expand
>   the limits of the plot so they are visible), but all other aesthetics
>   are set. This means that layers created with this function will never
>   affect the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
days<-rep(Sys.Date(),100)+seq(1,100)
v<-sin(as.numeric(days))
df<-data.frame(days=c(days,days),v=c(v,cos(v)+.1),n=c(rep('a',100),rep('b',100)))

shade <- data.frame(x1=c(as.Date('2016-10-15'),as.Date('2017-11-11')), 
                    x2=c(as.Date('2016-10-20'),as.Date('2017-11-13')), 
                    y1=c(-Inf,-Inf), y2=c(Inf,Inf))

plot(ggplot(df, aes(x=days, y=v, colour=n)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_rect(data=shade, inherit.aes = F,
            aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2), 
            color = 'grey', alpha=0.2) +
  geom_point())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would setting limits based on `range(df$days)` work for your situation?

```
my_limits <- range(df$days)

ggplot(df, aes(x=days, y=v, colour=n)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_rect(data=shade, inherit.aes = F,
           aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2), 
           color = 'grey', alpha=0.2) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_date(limits = my_limits) # See scale_x_datetime in case the data has time too.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution creates rectangle plot and adds it to the main plot if `days`
are within interval of `shade`. Date manipulation is performed using `lubridate` package.

```
# Main plot that doesn't change depending on time interval
pMain <- ggplot(df, aes(days, v, colour = n)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()

# Time manipulation part
library(lubridate)
# Turn character string to dates
df$days <- ymd(df$days)
shade$x1 <- ymd(shade$x1)
shade$x2 <- ymd(shade$x2)

# Check which shade entries contain days 
foo <- c()
for(i in nrow(shade)) {
    bar <- any(df$days %within% interval(shade[i, ]$x1, shade[i, ]$x2))
    if (bar) {
        foo <- c(foo, i)
    }
}

# If any interval contained days
# Create rectangle plot and add it to the main plot
CONTAINS <- length(foo) > 0
if (CONTAINS) {
    pRect <-  geom_rect(data=shade[foo, ], inherit.aes = F,
                aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2), 
                color = 'grey', alpha=0.2)
    pMain <- pMain + pRect
}
plot(pMain)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just filter `shade` before giving it to ggplot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
days<-rep(Sys.Date(),100)+seq(1,100)
v<-sin(as.numeric(days))
df<-data.frame(days=c(days,days),v=c(v,cos(v)+.1),n=c(rep('a',100),rep('b',100)))

shade <- data.frame(x1=c(as.Date('2016-10-15'),as.Date('2017-11-11')), 
                    x2=c(as.Date('2016-10-20'),as.Date('2017-11-13')), 
                    y1=c(-Inf,-Inf), y2=c(Inf,Inf)) %>%
  filter(between(x1, min(df$days), max(df$days)), between(x2, min(df$days), max(df$days)))

plot(ggplot(df, aes(x=days, y=v, colour=n)) +
       geom_line() +
       geom_rect(data=shade, inherit.aes = F,
                 aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2), 
                 color = 'grey', alpha=0.2) +
       geom_point())
```

Comment: Where is `shade2` defined?

Comment: Woops; it should have been `shade`. I've edited the answer.